# How to add an existing lib need to be built to my own project

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm currently working on a project in C++. I use autotools, I'm new for it BTW, to make the building system. An existing library with a makefile must be used in my project. Because it's a rarely used library, for the sake of portability I need to copy the entire sources in the my project directory and ask makefile to build the library with its own makefile before building my codes. What should I do? I have no clue how to add code in Makefile.am or somewhere like it. Any helpful answers are appreciated.

Comment: Is there a possibility of using shell scripts? Can you also elaborate on the build environment you are targeting (Windows[MinGW/Cygwin]/GNU Linux or MacOS)?

Comment: Supposedly, it's going to work on both Linux and MacOS. I'm coding on MacOS now. In my case they are the same actually, since I almost only use GNU tool chain and manage the packages with macports. @AmeyaVS

Comment: Can you update in the question using the edit button and provide the necessary details?

Comment: see this [project](https://github.com/deminets/unimake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two parts:

1. Build the library as recommended by the library's README or instructions.  You might have to choose options to produce an acceptable flavor of shareable library.
2. To your project, add the output shareable library as a library for inclusion.  You probably will also have to add a declarations file (.h) to it somewhere too.

It might be expedient to include the library directly into your project in (IMHO) rare cases.  However, resist that urge:  It usually causes trouble with symbols (namespace pollution and namimg conflicts) and messes up assumptions about how the interfaces are supposed to work.  It also makes source code control more difficult.

With the recommended separation of projects (yours v. library), usually some degree of smarts are needed to conditionally rebuild the project if the library has changed.  That can be done with a encapsulating makefile which first calls `make the_library` then calls `make myproject`.  Or you can manually invoke the proper makefiles  which would be more convenient since the library—once it is working satisfactorily—probably won't need any work.

Comment: I think your suggestion is great. Simple and clean. I'll follow it. @wallyk